# How to get the component inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a JTable inside a JScrollPane; How can I get the JTable?

Thanks

Comment: By its object, yes, no? Need to see your code snippet first then we can talk :)

Comment: Go into a debugger and keep exploring the children variable of component starting with all the children of the JScrollPane, then all the children of those children, etc, it's bound to be there somewhere.

Comment: Presumably(1) a `JTable` is in a `JScrollPane` because your code created it and put it there.  Keep a reference to the `JTable` when it is created.  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @SSCCE I tried: _(JTable)(((JViewport)(((JScrollPane)m_Tabs.getComponentAt(idx)).getComponent(0))).getView())_ and it works. thank you guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport(); 
JTable mytable = (JTable)viewport.getView();
```

Comment: near: but slightly too complicated: scrollPane.getViewportView() - the general rule is: if there are delegate methods, do use them :-)

Comment: I cannot find a method getViewportView() for JScrollPane, so the first answer seems right. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

Answer (score 1):

you have to extract `JTable` from `JViewport`, and `JViewport` from `JScrollPane`

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SingleTableTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SingleTableTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Vector<Vector<String>> rowData = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        Vector<String> columnName = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList("Column 1"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            rowData.add(new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(Integer.toString(i))));
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnName);
        //JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
        vertical.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        add(scrollPane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        JViewport view = scrollPane.getViewport();
        Component[] components =view.getComponents();
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < components.length; i1++) {
            if (components[i1] instanceof JTable) {
                System.out.println("Hehehehr here is heídden that JTable");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SingleTableTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hehehehr here is heídden that JTable - LOL!